# Alternative of Screencast.com Video Embedder video plugin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to use videos from [www.screencast.com](http://www.screencast.com) in WordPress want to to show multiple links for videos in single page and when I click on a  link it should the video in popup form.

I tried this "Screencast.com Video Embedder " but this is not opening videos in popup from.

Please Help.

Comment: Can you show a URL where this behavior is acting as such?  It may just be a situation where you have to manipulate the code within the plugin.

Comment: If not, does this plugin do what you're trying to do?  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-video-plugin/

Comment: @JasonWeber "wordpress-video-plugin " supports screencast-o-matic.com not the www.screencast.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the embed code from the screencast.com share option and paste that into your post's html.  Then go back to the visual mode and adjust the dimensions if necessary to fit your screen (600 px or whatever).

Better yet, when you look at the Screencast site, instead of grabbing the “Embed On Your Page” code, simply look above at the “Share URL.”  This is the content you’ll need to add to the Screencast Short Code. Make sure you grab “http:……../” and everything.  So your shortcode should look like this;

```
[screencast url="http:www.screeencast.com/123XYZabc" width="xxx" height="yyy"]
```

The next plugin you'll need doesn't get rave reviews, but I do know some people who've used this successfully.  I know it's old, but apparently still works.  [Popup Video Generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/popup-video-generator/).  And here's an [example of how to use it properly](http://www.justmakemedia.com/news/2010/10/popup-video-generator-wordpress-plugin/).